# With the cheapest possible graphics card for a super fast processor, will the processor have maximum performance?

Tags: linux, cpu, performance, gpu, workstation

If I get the cheapest possible graphics card for a super fast processor will the processor have maximum performance?

I need a graphics card due to the fact that Ryzen 7700x does not have good drivers for the integrated one and I have strange hangs on Linux.

My question is if I can give any graphics card and use 100% of the power of the CPU.

Can I get any graphics card or do I have to pay attention to something?

I would like to point out that I do not use games and the PC is only used to work on multiple simultaneous programs. Not necessarily graphics programs, but a lot in browsers and office programs which uses a lot of computing power and RAM.

// edit

I see lists on benchmark that show the performance of the computer depending and there are clearly stated cards that are suitable.

I know that they mainly test games there, but I wonder if a weak graphics card will somehow slow down the processor to use it to its maximum potential - some kind of bottleneck ?

//edit

Now I use the integrated graphics card for the processor but yesterday had a strange system hang for about 10 seconds? could this be the fault of the lack of drivers (linux) for the integrated graphics card for ryzen - it seems that from the "graphics" however depends on the operation of the operating system

Comment: If you aren't running GPU intensive tasks, then a "weak" GPU won't hamper CPU at all

Comment: Yeah.  Servers have really simple (like VGA) graphics cards...

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with the above, and I am guessing from the fact you mention Linux it will be a Linux machine. Windows does make more use of some of 3d features, that may have some impact (even the I don't think it would be noticeable.  But if you are using non-graphical intense stuff there should be no issues.  Modern cheap graphics cards are fine for "office stuff".

Comment: well, but I do not understand because I see statements on benchmark that show the performance of the computer depending, and there are clearly stated cards that are suitable. 

I know that they test there mostly games but I wonder if if if in the judge a weak graphics card it will not slow down the processor in some way - some bottleneck ?

Comment: @davidgo  then why integrated graphics hung my Linux for 10 seconds yesterday ? this is not what I expected when buying a mega fast processor for work....

Comment: @byggy I cant deduce what you are talking about with respect of integrated graphics haning your Linux for 10 seconds yesterday.   You have not advised what you are doing to invoke this hanging or where it is occurring.   Also, a script/driver pausing for 10 seconds on Linux may not affect other processes.  I do wonder if its a kernel thing relating to trying to deduce what video card you are running - maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526162/random-freezes-with-amd-ryzen-on-linux is relevant?

Comment: @davidgo I have no idea. I just used chrome browser and had a hang for 10 seconds. New hardware and it doesn't work well from the start - strange. Maybe you are right that it doesn't see the exact hardware because in the Display tab I have a device (Unknow Display) - on the old laptop it could see what monitor it was using without any problems and here it's lame even though I have fresh ubuntu 22 and on the old one was ubuntu 20

Comment: You ask about cpu performance (implyong tasks that require cpu and not gpu)  with a poor graphics card, but then run stuff that requires a moderate gpu (Chrome - which also implies a Windowing system) and complain that gpu prrformance is bad.  Ofcourse if you buy a bad/cheap GPU tasks which use the GPU will not perform well.   Maybe you should hsve advisef the model of gpu you bought and asked how to get it to work properly on askubuntu.com s/e.

Comment: after all, thanks for your time and explanation, that is, however to work you need graphics since as you write even chrome needs it. I understand that the same is with firefox and other browsers it will turn out that even libreoffice requires graphics?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the tasks you will be loading your CPU with do not depend on the GPU at all (no graphics rendering, no GPU accelerated video decoding/encoding), no CUDA / OpenCL or 3D rendering.

These tasks will not be hampered with a weak GPU. If you have tasks that WILL rely on the GPU to complete in time, then yes, you'll need to pay attention to the GPU performance.

What I would recommend would be to look for a card that is well supported on your particular linux distribution and run with that.

What *could* limit the performance of your processor for purely CPU bound tasks is the speed / latency of your RAM. Possibly storage depending on the volume of data yo uhave to work with.

Comment: Just a note: Bechmarks that show the performance of the computer depending on the GPU in addition to the CPU usually run a workload that is relying on the GPU for some work (e.g. games)

Comment: So I understand that I can give even some old gtx 660 - And I will not have any decrease in productivity not at work? Now I use the integrated graphics card for the processor but yesterday had a strange system hang for about 10 seconds? could this be the fault of the lack of drivers for the integrated graphics card for ryzen - it seems that from the "graphics" however depends on the operation of the operating system

Comment: Again, this depends on *your* workload, if all you use the GPU for is displaying the desktop, then yes, a GTX 660 will be more than adequate, as long as it solves your hangs  issues. Did you check your system logs followings those hangs to check if they really came from what you supposed they were coming from ?

Comment: Do you mean the dsmeg command or some other command? I understand that now I can no longer read it what was yesterday? @irwene

Comment: Yes, dmesg would be a good first troubleshooting step, you need to know for sure why you have a freeze otherwise, adding an discrete GPU might not help.